# program enlarges when transferred to another computer in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I hope you can understand what I will ask, I use Netbeans as my IDE and I use Java as my language. I made a program using Jframe from another computer, when I transferred it to another computer, everything enlarges and I cant just change the preferred size of the Jframe because only the Jframe becomes small and not the other component. Hope anyone can help me

Comment: screen resolutions of both PCs are different? I'm guessing the aspect ratio on one is greater than the other and it seems "bigger" on the one with the smaller aspect ratio.

Comment: What do you mean by everything enlarges?  Do you mean literally enlarges, or is larger relative to the screen size?  What do you mean by "everything"?  Components?  Fonts?  Images?

Comment: This is where making use of appropriate layout managers is so important